# Spaces NSURL connection

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I am trying to have a name field that people can put there name in and it will send to a php page.

I have got this working without the spaces with this code...

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender {

    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/ios/contact.php?name=%@", nameField.text];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    self.request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.nsCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];


    NSLog(@"out put = %@", self.request);
}
```

But as soon as I use a space adder fix it wont be picked up by my php page, evan though the log says its working.

[image]

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender {

    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/ios/contact.php?name=", nameField.text];

    strURL = [strURL stringByAppendingString:nameField.text];
    strURL = [strURL stringByAppendingString:@"'"];
    strURL = [strURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    self.request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.nsCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];


    NSLog(@"out put = %@", self.request);
}
```

Have I got a syntax error, or approaching this method in the wrong way?

My .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContactViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
}
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (strong) NSURLConnection *nsCon;
@property (strong) NSURLConnection *request;
@property (strong) NSURLConnection *receivedData;

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, may not fix your problem, instead of stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method, you should use [unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` before you make a request.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                 [[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]        
                 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

For your code try this.

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender {

    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/ios/contact.php?name=%@", nameField.text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                     [[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]        
                     stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

    self.request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.nsCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"out put = %@", self.request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply!! I have one error with that code as soon as we fix i will mark correct. heres a link to image. http://s10.postimage.org/eb0pw9m3t/Screen_Shot_2013_03_06_at_16_58_27.png

Comment: I updated it to use NSUTF8StringEncoding but now i dont get any output with spaces.